# Size of the markers with mobile view

Tags: svg, view, size, here-api

using Here maps on mobile devices will reduce the size of the markers in the view dramaticlly. The images are very small (SVGs).

Here you can try: https://www.gruppenunterkuenfte.de/Pension--Seminarhaus-Am-Alten-Weinberg__t12498.html

What to do against it?

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do:

If you're using normal H.map.Marker instances (with H.map.Icon) you can detect the hi-dpi multiplier through `window.devicePixelRatio` and apply that multiplier manually.

The second options is to have the browser handle it via the H.map.DomMarker (with H.map.DomIcon). This marker is slightly heavier in rendering (as it uses actual DOM nodes instead of rendering on the map canvas) but will size according to CSS pixel sizes - i.e. at the same size no matter what device pixel ratio. In your case the DomMarker won't be an issue since you only display a single marker.

Check here for details how to set up the different kinds of markers: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/markers.html

Comment: Hi. Great! It works: var scale=window.devicePixelRatio;var bearsIcon = new H.map.Icon(image, { size: {w:40*scale,h:53*scale}}); Thanks a lot